# Worldbuilding Data Queries

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

This post is here to house SEDE (StackExchange Data Explorer) queries relating to this site. Originally spawned from [this thread](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2007/what-data-queries-would-be-useful-here).

Queries are categorised below depending on the data they look at. If you have written a query and would like it added to the list, just edit it in in the correct category (if you feel there is no category, create one). **Please do not add new answers for other queries.** I've made the answer CW so most people can edit, however if you have insufficient reputation and would like your query added, leave it in a comment below or talk to someone in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/worldbuilders-general-chat).

If you feel like you can improve on a query, just fork the query using the link in SEDE and make your changes. You can change the link in the answer when you're done.

Comment: This queries could benefit other Stack Exchange sites. Should we post this on Meta, or do something related?

Comment: We could do, some sites (TWP notably) already have some. I can post it today.

Comment: Suggested addition: [Tag Experts](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/300939/tag-experts), lists the person with the highest answer score for each tag. Not sure if it's useful, especially on low-traffic tags, but it might be nice to find your name somewhere on the list. Mostly I just like making up new queries.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Do feel free just to edit things in :)

Comment: I've found this, it could be of interest : https://www.quantcast.com/worldbuilding.stackexchange.com#!demo

Comment: i dont understand what query and it real purpose is, but looking at some answer i have a gist of it. would it be possible to add previous hot network list question regarding world building? especially our own.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Voting and Moderation

- [**Upvotes Over Time**](http://data.stackexchange.com/opensource/query/335866/votes-over-time?VoteType=2#graph) - shows how many votes each post received on average over time.
- [**Percentage of questions closed**](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/300940/percentage-of-questions-closed) - shows a simple rundown of total questions, closed questions, and the percentage of questions closed.

## Post Statistics

- [**Distribution of Votes on Answers**](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/300919/distribution-of-votes-on-answers#graph) - shows how many answers have how many votes. I find the graph most interesting here.
- [**Distribution of Votes on Questions**](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/300923/distribution-of-votes-on-questions#graph) - shows how many *questions* have how many votes. Again, the graph is very interesting.
- [**Asked/Closed/Reopened per week**](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/300932/asked-closed-reopened-per-week#graph) - shows the number of questions asked, closed and reopened together in a graph.
- [**Status Percentages of Questions Asked Each Week**](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/313404/status-percentages-of-questions-asked-each-week#graph) - shows the percentage of questions asked each week that have accepted an answer, have been closed, or are still open.
- [**Number of questions with respective number of answers**](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/300931/number-of-questions-with-respective-number-of-answers#graph) - shows the number of questions that has each specific number of answers. (For example, how many questions have 0 answers, 1 answer, 2 answers, ..., 10 answers, ...)
- [**Closed Question Information**](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/353426/closed-question-info) - Compilation of closed questions with some useful data. For full use, you may need to write your own filtering criteria, right now it's at least useful for finding all of the closed questions asked during a certain time or by a certain user.
- [**What questions have the highest ratio of votes to views?**](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/403565/what-questions-have-the-highest-ratio-of-votes-to-views?MinViewCount=2500&MinScore=10&LastNDays=6000) Highlight "high-quality" questions, with high votes relative to the viewcounts.

## Posts to Watch

- [**Possible low-quality answers**](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/300384/possible-downvote-worthy-answers) - gives a list of answers which satisfy some common criteria of low-quality answers. Note that being in this list does not automatically make an answer low quality, they should still be evaluated on their own merits.
- [**Possible low-quality answers - Interactive version**](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/302938/possible-downvote-worthy-answers-interactive?MaxBodyLength=500&ScoreUpperThreshold=0&MinComments=0) - a version of the possible low-quality answers query that lets you set your own thresholds.
- [**New Answers to Old Questions**](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/302141/new-answers-to-old-questions) - shows answers from the last week posted on questions more than 30 days older.
- [**Highest Voted Posts**](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/302101/highest-voted-posts) - gives the top 15 highest voted posts from the last week.
- [**Lowest Voted Posts**](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/302107/lowest-voted-posts) - gives the top 15 lowest voted posts from the last week.
- [**Most Commented**](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/302123/most-commented) - lists the 15 most commented posts of the last week.
- [**Most Viewed**](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/302126/most-viewed) - lists the 15 most viewed questions of the last week.
- [**Most Edited**](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/302129/most-edited) - lists the 15 most edited posts that were last edited in the last week.

## Users

- [**Suggested Edits Reputation League**](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/1244442/suggested-edits-reputation-league?n=100) - tells the top users in terms of the reputation earned from suggesting edits.
- [**Distinct Contributors per week**](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/171748/distinct-contributors-per-week#graph) - shows the number of *different* users engaged in different activities per week. Taken directly from [TWP](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2667/27355).
- [**New Users per week**](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/161189/users-by-date-joined#graph) - shows the number of new users who joined each week. Again, from TWP.
- [**New User Progress**](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/300967/newuserprogress?daysSinceJoined=14) - shows newly-contributing users, showing numbers of questions/answers and rep.
- [**User Total and Average Scores on Questions Asked**](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/372267/list-of-questions-of-a-given-user) - shows average and total votes by user across all questions asked, for users with more than 10 questions.
- [**User Question/Answer Count/Score/Average**](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/489021/counts-and-scores-and-averages-for-questions-and-answers) - Shows the count of questions and answers, the total score for questions and answers, and the average score for questions and answers for users with more than 500 rep.
- [**How Socratic Are We?**](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/405626/curious-inquisitive-socratic-badge-progresse) Shows counts of positively scoring questions asked in distinct days, for all users, ranked by total counts. Helpful for those hunting for "Socratic" badges, perhaps?

## Tags

- [**Tag Usage over time**](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/300992/tag-usage-over-time?TagName=science-based#graph) - shows how much a tag has been used over time as a graph of number of posts against time.
- [**Tag Experts**](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/300939/tag-experts) - shows the user who has the highest answer score for each tag.
- [**Tag Expertise**](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/499298/tag-expertise) - shows in how many tags the user is top expert (based on the Tag Experts script above)

## General Activity/Utility

- [**Site Activity and Voting graph**](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/161411/site-activity-and-votegraph#graph) - a graph of significant stats like votes, questions and answers, all per week. Copied from TWP.
- [**Questions and Answers Posted Each Day of the Week**](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/322527/answersbydayofweek) - proof that we're all doing this instead of getting work done :)
- [**Posts and user activity by hour of week**](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/334859/posting-users-and-posts-by-hour-of-week-gmt#graph) - 00:00 Sun to 23:59 Sat UTC, averaged over history of the site (change DaysOfHistory if you want something more recent).

Comment: The low-quality posts query is awesome. It beats automatic flagging.

Comment: @HDE226868 I've managed to lose a good 20 rep from downvote get answers off that query...

Comment: I've done some similar voting.

Answer (score 4):

## Badges Progress

Some of the users like to see how they fare with their virtual rewards, namely badges. And sometimes it isn't easy to know how much more we have to wait before we get such and such badge. Here are some queries which can give some views on those. Or explanation on how to get to know.

#### Questions

- [Curious](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/87/curious) / [Inquisitive](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/88/inquisitive) / [Socratic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/89/socratic):
- [Favorite Question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/33/favorite-question) /  [Stellar Question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/36/stellar-question):
- [Nice Question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/20/nice-question) / [Good Question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/21/good-question) / [Great Question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/22/great-question):
- [Popular Question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/26/popular-question) / [Notable Question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/27/notable-question) / [Famous Question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/28/famous-question):
- [Tumbleweed](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/40/tumbleweed):

#### Answers

- [Enlightened](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/19/enlightened)
- [Refiner](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/91/refiner) / [Illuminator](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/92/illuminator)
- [Generalist](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/15/generalist) => [Generalist Progression](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/435407/generalist-progression-updated)
- [Guru](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/18/guru)
- [Nice Answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer) / [Good Answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/24/good-answer) / [Great Answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/25/great-answer)
- [Populist](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/39/populist)
- [Reversal](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/57/reversal)
- [Revival](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/64/revival)
- [Necromancer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/17/necromancer)
- [Self-Learner](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/14/self-learner)
- [Tenacious](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/50/tenacious) / [Unsung Hero](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/51/unsung-hero)

#### Participation

- [Commentator](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/31/commentator)
- [Pundit](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/56/pundit) => [Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/293394/how-long-until-i-get-the-pundit-badge) for a given user.
- [Enthusiast](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/54/enthusiast) / [Fanatic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/55/fanatic):
- [Epic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/42/epic) / [Legendary](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/43/legendary) => [When did you reach the cap?](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/235570/epic-legendary-progress-which-days-were-it)
- [Beta](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/30/beta)
- [Convention](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/68/convention) => [How close am I to a convention badge?](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/166532/how-close-am-i-to-convention-badge)
- [Talkative](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/65/talkative)
- [Outspoken](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/69/outspoken)
- [Yearling](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13/yearling)

#### Moderation

- [Deputy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/70/deputy) / [Marshal](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/76/marshal)
- [Civic Duty](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty)
- [Reviewer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/78/reviewer) / [Steward](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/83/steward)
- [Strunk & White](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white) / [Copy Editor](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/49/copy-editor):
- [Electorate](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/electorate)
- [Archaeologist](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/74/archaeologist)
- [Proofreader](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/73/proofreader)
- [Sportsmanship](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/63/sportsmanship)
- [Suffrage](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/62/suffrage)
- [Research Assistant](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/79/research-assistant)
- [Taxonomist](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist)
- [Vox Populi](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/71/vox-populi)

#### Others

- [Announcer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/announcer) / [Booster](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/60/booster) / [Publicist](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/61/publicist)